# JPA Tools is generating entities with "old"/deleted columns from database

Tags: java, jpa

I am working with JPA tools and I successfully generated multiple times the entities from tables. When I needed to delete them in order to generate them back, I sometimes had cases where the entities had duplicated field and/or old fields that weren't supposed to be there because the column didn't exist anymore.
Right now I cannot post examples of this because my pc is downloading/working on some stuff, but as soon as it's done, I will post some of my problems.
Any clue on why is this happening?

Comment: Trying out some magical spell! But guess what, its impossible to comment without any proper code or configurations!

Comment: All transactions on the database should better be closed. One can try a small test: get the `DataBaseMetaData` from the `Connection` to inspect the columns.